# JavaのReaderクラスの考え方について

Tags: java

Wrtiterにも同じ疑問を感じているのですが、

JavaのReaderクラスについて、Javadocには

> 文字ストリームを読み込むための abstract クラスです。
>   (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/java/io/Reader.html)

と書かれていますが、Readerを継承しているStringReaderクラスについては、

> ソースが文字列の文字ストリームです。
>   (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/java/io/StringReader.html)

と書かれていますが、Reader関係のクラスは、ストリームその物なのでしょうか？
それともストリームを読み込むための物なのでしょうか？

皆さんは、どのように捉えられているのでしょうか？お教えてください。

Comment: ストリームを扱う（読み込むための）クラスですね。ストリームその物ではなくて、内部的にストリームを保持していてそれを扱うということだと思います。

Comment: ストリーム自身のクラスとしては例えば`InputStream`の系列が（入力）ストリームを表現するクラスなのでそういう意味でこちらがストリームその物（のクラス）です。

Comment: 完全に私の想像なのですが、`StringReader`が(実際にはそうではないのに)「ストリームです」と書かれているのは、[`StringBufferInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html)がJDK1.1でdeprecatedになり、代わりに`StringReader`を使え、みたいな流れ上筆が滑ったのかな…と。///コンストラクタの説明では「文字列リーダー」と表現されていますね。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Reader`や`Writer`は例えばファイルの読み書きに用いられますが、一般のプログラムが直接HDDを操作してファイルを取り出すことはありません。ファイルシステムはOSの制御にあります。

ですので、ファイルをオープンしたとき、実際には以下のような流れがあります。

- OSのファイル読み出しの命令を呼び出す
- OSがドライバソフトウェアを用いてハードウェアを操作する
- ファイル実体のバイト列が得られる
- OSからバイト列が返却される

このようなIOで受け渡されるバイトの流れのことを、ストリームと呼びます。この概念を抽象化したのが`InputStream`になります。

ファイルを例に取りましたが、実体となるストリームのソースは通信であったり、ハードディスクであったり、メモリだったりします。`InputStream`そのものは「バイト列を1バイトずつ扱う」ことを定めたインターフェースとなります。

ここで、もし入力がテキストだと分かっているのであれば、エンコードしながら一文字ずつ読み込んだ方が便利ですよね。「文字列のストリームを1文字ずつ扱う」ことを定めたインターフェースが`Reader`です。`Reader`も`InputStream`同様、実体が何かは知りません。

`StringReader`はJavaプログラム上の文字列を「入力ストリーム」として扱いたい場合に利用します。実体（ソース）は`String`インスタンスです。こちらはインターフェースではなく実装になりますね。

---

「*ソースが文字列の文字ストリームです。*」という日本語だと分かりにくいですが、

1. 1バイトずつ読み込む「ストリーム」と、1文字ずつ読み込む「文字ストリーム」の2種類が区別されている。
2. 「ストリームからどう読み込むか」のインターフェースと、「何のストリームからどう読み込むか」の実装がある。
3. ソースが`String`（文字列）の`StringReader`（文字ストリームを扱う実装）がある。

と順を追って考えると分かりやすいのではないでしょうか。

> Reader関係のクラスは、ストリームその物なのでしょうか？
>   それともストリームを読み込むための物なのでしょうか？

という質問に対しては、「ストリームを読み込むためのもの」という答えになります。